# 3ds max "flatten"/group move vertices

Tags: 3d-modeling, 3ds-max

How can I move selection of vertices to a specific point/line.

I have a diagonal line of vertices, however I'd like to make them flat ( parallel to the x axis) if I select the group of vertices and move them it just moves them in a diagonal line, however I'd like to be able to set them all to a specific  coordinate. I could go through them one by one, but this boring and slow and highly in efficient.

Basically how do I make a line of vertices from this:

```
. 
  .
    .
      .
```

to

```
. . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest solution I have found is:

-Make sure the object is an editable poly.
-Select the vertices you would like to align.
-scroll down to make planar and click X (or Y or Z) depending on the direction you would like to move the vertices in. this aligns the selected vertices.
-now you can just set the coordinate

hope it helps